# Scala solution to nQueen using for-comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, n-queens

I have some difficulty in understanding the Scala solution to the [n Queens problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html), below is the implementation assuming isSafe is defined correctly

```
def queens(n: Int): Set[List[Int]] = {
    def placeQueens(k: Int): Set[List[Int]] = k match {
        case 0 => Set(List())
        case _ =>
            for {
                queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
                col <- 0 until n
                if isSafe(col, queens   )
            }yield k :: queens
    }

    placeQueens(n)
  }
```

The for comprehension, as I have seen, theoretically should return a buffered collection, and I see here it buffers a list of queens with `k :: queens`, but it indeed returns a `Set[List]` as defined. Can someone throw some light on how this `for` comprehension works?

Is my assumption correct that `for` every time will return a collection of collections and since in this case I deal with a Seq and a Set in the nested for for expression it is returning a `Set[List]`.

The question is more related to the `for` comprehension in implementing nQueen not nQueen in general.

Comment: I think the following expression gives a little bit of a clear picture of what happens in the background the expression `for(x <- e1; y <- e2) yield e3` is broken into too separate expression `for(y <- e2) yield e3` flat mapped with the first expression resulting in `e1.flatMap(x => for (y <- e2) yield e3)`, so in the above case each list of yielded `queens` must be flat mapped to a Set which is the top level collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a for comprehension is just syntactic sugar for map, flatmap and filter, all three of which you are using in your example. Whatever you yield in the yield block will be added to the mapped collection. You might find [this article on how yield works](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) to be interesting.

When you yield `k :: queens` you are creating a list with k added to the queens list which was generated from a recursive invocation using `k-1`.

Your assumption is correct. The `for` comprehension will return the types of lists involved. Since placeQueens returns a `Set[List[Int]]` so will the for comprehension. The translation of your `for` comprehension is like this:

```
placeQueens(k-1).flatMap { queens => 
  (0 until n).withFilter { col => 
    isSafe(col, queens)
  }.map { col => 
    k::queens
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, that `for` comprehension, in essence, when applied to a sequence, describes mapping of elements of a this sequence using a function which is specified inside the body of `for`-comprehension. Therefore, the end result will be the collection of the original outer type (i.e. `Set`, `List` or any other `Seq`-descendant) over the type returned by the body of `for`-comprehension.

In your case, the outer type is `Set` and the inner type is the type of `k :: queens` (which is `List[Int]`, because `queens` is an element from the sequence returned by `placeQueens`, which is `Set[List[Int]]`, and `k::queens` returns the sequence of the same type as `queens`.